# set a boolean variable to true and another ones to false in javascript?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, switch-statement, boolean

I want to know if there is way I can simplify this code:

```
        switch(visibleMenu) {
            case "menu": {
                mainMenu = true;
                assignment = false;
                temary = false;
                break;
            }
            case "asignment": {
                mainMenu = false;
                assignment = true;
                temary = false;
                break;
            }
            case "temary": {
                mainMenu = false;
                assignment = false;
                temary = true;
            }
        }
```

I don't like to repeat so many times each word. Ideas?

Comment: Why do you need to set additional variables? Why not just check visibleMenu === “assignment” for example? You could take it a step further and define an enum so you’ve got visibleMenu === Menu.Assignment instead of direct string comparison

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems this will do it:

```
 mainMenu = visibleMenu === 'menu';
 assignment = visibleMenu === 'asignment';
 temary = visibleMenu === 'temary';
```

There is no need for a **`switch`** statement